# Each element in $\overline M^w$ is the weak limit of a sequence in $M$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, weak-convergence

> Let $X$ be a normed $\mathbb K$-vector space and $\overline M^w$ the closure of a subset $M ⊂ X$ with respect to the weak topology $σ(X,X^∗)$. Decide whether each element in $\overline M^w$ is the weak limit of a sequence in $M$.

My intuition says that this is not true. Usually, one works in such cases with a counter example where you define a set in a conveniently chosen space and show by contradiction that the statement is not true. I wanted to consider a set $M=\{ x \in X : \Vert x \Vert = 1\}$ but I got stuck how to choose a Banach space to show that my this statement is wrong.

I would be glad if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest examples that I know are
$$M = \{ \sqrt{n}\,e_n \mid n \in \mathbb N\} \subset \ell^2$$
and
$$N = \{ e_n + n \, e_m \mid n,m \in \mathbb N, m \ge n \} \subset \ell^2.$$
In both cases, you can show that $0$ belongs to the weak closure, but no sequence converges weakly to $0$.

Furthermore, $N$ has the following property: Let us denote by $\operatorname{cl}_w^{\text{seq}}A$ the set of weak limit points of weakly convergent sequences with elements in a set $A$. Then, $0 \in \operatorname{cl}_w^{\text{seq}}\operatorname{cl}_w^{\text{seq}}N \setminus \operatorname{cl}_w^{\text{seq}} N$.

The set $M$, however, is weakly sequentially closed, i.e., the weak limits of all weakly convergent sequences belongs to $M$.

Comment: Thanks for the examples! But why does one do this specially for $0$ and not a general $x$?

Comment: Because $0$ is the problematic point for this sets.